# Browse files in server

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache

I'm trying to stream videos stored in the server to a client. The browse button in HTML is used to browse only the client side files. How do I browse server files or any particular directory?

What i have :

```
<video id='videoPlayer' width="320" height="240" poster="untitled.jpg" controls autoplay>    
    <source id='mp4Sources' src="" type="video/mp4">     
    <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240"> 
        <embed width="320" height="240" src="movie.swf"> 
    </object>     
</video>
```

Comment: <video id='videoPlayer' width="320" height="240" poster="untitled.jpg" controls autoplay>
<source id='mp4Sources' src="" type="video/mp4">
  <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
    <embed width="320" height="240" src="movie.swf">
  </object>
</video>

Comment: I wish to change the video source using javascript by browsing and selecting files in server..

Comment: What good does code do us in a comment?  And I'm pretty sure Rahul is referring to your javascript or php.  If you expect a response with effort, you have to give it in return.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server setup, they probably can't (and shouldn't) be able to browse through any directory they please.

If you just want to give them a file download then just give them the URL: **http://yourdomain.com/path/to/file**

If you're confused about how to browse the server to upload/manipulate files, you'll probably need an FTP program. Try Filezilla, or see if your server has one built into a web interface you can access. From there you will log into your server and move files between your computer and the remote server.

If you're looking to build an interface for them to upload a file and then share the link, that's a much more complicated question involving form submission and file validation.

If you have all of that taken care of and need to make the video stream instead of downloading directly, check this article for more in-depth info than I can give here: http://www.mediacollege.com/video/streaming/overview.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ll refer to the link you mentioned.